# CSS Hack to Target Firefox 3.5+?

Tags: css, firefox

Firefox 3.5 now supports the nth-* pseudoclass, which was what I was using to target my css for Safari and Chrome. Now Firefox reads those too, causing minor layout issues. Does anyone know a way to specifically target FF 3.5+?

```
BODY:nth-of-type(1) #topsearch input[type=submit] /* Safari 3.1+ and Chrome */ { 
     height:19px 
}
```

Comment: to me this sounds like wrong use of css, if you have to target each browser separately. especially if you're talking about browsers which all understand a certain CSS3 feature. since I don't know your context, I can be wrong.

Comment: tharkun, using CSS hacks to target specific browsers (to get rendered pages to look the same in all browsers) are commonplace. Unfortunate facts of a designer's life.

Comment: Why are you trying to fix your problem with a hack?  Show us the actual CSS code and we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I should go to a designer's forum but here is an example:
BODY:nth-of-type(1) #topsearch input[type=submit] /* Safari 3.1+  and Chrome */
{ height:19px }

This is also now read in FF 3.5, where I need the height value to be different.

Comment: @nonagon: I try to write applications, create layouts and consequently write CSS that doesn't need any hacks. It's not always possible with IE6, but for the rest, yes!

Comment: @nonagon: Hardly commonplace. Most qualified web designers avoid browser-specific CSS hacks like the plague (with the possible exception of IE6)

Comment: @tharkun, I agree it's hardly commonplace, but it's also not always possible.  Yes IE6 was a major offender, but Firefox does its own thing sometimes as well.  To say that targeting Firefox is NEVER a good idea is a bit presumptuous.  @Weegee - you might be able to fix his problem another way, but this is the question he asked, and it's a valid one.

Answer (score 5):

How about this, I tested it in Safari 4 and the height is 19px, in Firefox 3.5 the height displays as 39px.

```
<style>

BODY:nth-of-type(1) #topsearch input[type=submit] /* Safari 3.1+ and Chrome */ { height:19px }      
BODY:nth-of-type(1) #topsearch input[type=submit], x:-moz-any-link, x:default { height: 39px; }

</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

[CSS Browser selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/) lets you write CSS that targets specific browsers, without worrying about hacks. I cannot recommend it highly enough.

Comment: @Bruce - that's a nice tool! It basically does a similar trick to what I posted but adds the classes to the html element.  Since that is the definitive top element, just specifying .gecko or .win or .safari handles everything like a charm!

Comment: @Bruce - one minor catch... as far as I can tell (at the moment) that tool won't provide a special class for ff3-5. That said, you can specifically target safari and chrome.

Comment: I know this posrt is really old, but I just found it.  Utter awesomeness, thanks!

Comment: The post might be old, but the solution is just as relevant today.

Answer (score 4):

On a "religious" note, we shouldn't be using CSS to target any browser.  Unfortunately due to IE being waaaay behind on supporting CSS features (and all the bugs) hacks have been applied to target CSS for a given browser.

The Conditional Comments that IE uses... although ugly... do provide a handy mechanism for targeting a browser (and version)... I almost wish other browsers supported this.

I've seen a few sites do this... which is an interesting approach to handling targeting of various browsers.

```
<head>
  <style>
    body.safari form input{
      /*special styles for Safari*/
    }
    body.firefox form input{
      /*special styles for Firefox*/
    } 
    body.firefox.v3-5 form input{
      /*special styles for Firefox 3.5*/
    } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    //run code here, that sets the class and or id attribute on the body tag...
  </script>
```

In the long run, they are all hacks... it just depends what kind of hacks you're willing to live with ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally the "BODY:nth-of-type(1) ..." syntax breaks YUI compressor's ability to minify CSS. Instead I use "body:first-of-type ...".

Answer (score 0):

[My approach](http://reinholdweber.com/css/css-hacks-browser-version-detection-a-new-approach/) using a PHP class to detect os, browser and browser version. You can target any version of almost any browser on any operating system.

Answer (score 0):

using http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

just substitute this part:

> is('firefox/2')?g+'
>   ff2':is('firefox/3')?g+' ff3'

for this part:

> is('firefox/2')?g+'
>   ff2':is('firefox/3.5')?g+'
>   ff3_5':is('firefox/3')?g+' ff3'

that should do the trick

PS: if you want to also catch other 3.x versions you might want to add:

> is('firefox/2')?g+'
>   ff2':is('firefox/3.5')?g+'
>   ff3_5':is('firefox/3.6')?g+'
>   ff3_5':is('firefox/3.8')?g+'
>   ff3_5':is('firefox/3')?g+' ff3'

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
    #topsearch input[type=submit] { height:19px; }
}}
```

That targets newer WebKit browsers, and not Gecko or Trident.

Answer (score 0):

A lot has changed in the last few years. For a Firefox 3.5+ hack, here is one I created for that purpose:

```
/* Firefox 3.5 and newer */

_:-moz-handler-blocked, :root .selector { property:value; }
```

To test it you can see these live along with many others for different versions of browser at my live CSS hacks test site here: http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/css_hacks.html#firefox

Enjoy!