# CSS Hack firefox 3.5 and below?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Is there any css hack for ff 3.5 and older (not 3.6) i used

```
.SubTabs ul, x:-moz-any-link
{
    /* IE7,6 Hack*/
    *top: -28px;
}
```

but this applies to all FF browser versions..

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159314/css-hack-to-target-firefox-3-5

Comment: well it might be related but he wants a hack that applies to 3.5 and newer...

Comment: the solution relevant to this quest with the http://rafael.adm.br/css%5Fbrowser%5Fselector/

Comment: sorry but it has no support for detecting ff 3.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well solved it some what not 100% perfect but should work

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js" />
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($.browser.mozilla) {
        $('body').addClass("mozilla");

        var versionParts = $.browser.version.split("\.");
        var version = 0;
        if (versionParts.length > 0) {
            version = version + versionParts[0] * 1000000000000;
        }
        if (versionParts.length > 1) {
            version = version + versionParts[1] * 1000000000;
        }
        if (versionParts.length > 2) {
            version = version + versionParts[2] * 1000000;
        }
        if (versionParts.length > 3) {
            version = version + versionParts[3] * 1000;
        }

        if (version >= 1009002000000) {
            $('body').addClass("mozilla3-6andAbove");
        }
        else {
            $('body').addClass("mozilla3-5andBelow");
        }
    }
});
```

now you can add body.mozilla3-5andBelow in your css file and it should work...

Comment: I avoid targeting browsers and their versions at all costs, but when your client still uses Firefox 3.5 and is not willing to upgrade, a solution like the one above is still best. That's why +1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [@-moz-document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@-moz-document) at-rule to target any version of Firefox, then override that selector for Firefox 3.6+ using the [@media -moz-scrollbar-start-backward](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries#-moz-scrollbar-start-backward) media query:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() 
 { 
 .SubTabs ul
  {
  top: -28px;
  }
 }

/* Firefox 3.6+ Filter */
@-moz-document url-prefix() 
 {  
 @media -moz-scrollbar-start-backward 
  { 
  .SubTabs ul
    {
    top: -10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating Firefox hacks for low end versions do require one for all, and a second one to override.

Here are a couple I created that do this.

The first one I posted to browserhacks.com so you may recognize it:

```
/* Firefox (any) */

_:-moz-tree-row(hover), .selector { top: 0px; }
```

Then the Override:

```
/* Firefox 3.6 and newer (use this to override) */

_:-moz-handler-crashed, :root .selector { top: -28px; }
```

To test these and many others live, you can try them out on my live css hacks test page: http://browserstrangeness.bitbucket.org/css_hacks.html#firefox

Enjoy!